# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Size must be known in advance when using READ_ALL

Tags: metaplex, mobile-wallet-adapter

I want to fetch an Account using the [SolanaKt](https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/SolanaKT) library

Code:

```
try {
    val serializer = SolanaAccountSerializer(ProgramInfo.serializer())
    val account = solana.api.getAccountInfo(serializer, getProgramInfoPda().address).getOrThrow()
    Log.d(TAG, "fetchQuestionCount: ${account}")
}
catch (e: Exception) {
    Log.d(TAG, "fetchQuestionCount Error: ${e}")
}
```

`ProgramInfo` class:

```
@Serializable
data class ProgramInfo(
    @Serializable(with = PublicKeyAs32ByteSerializer::class) val author: PublicKey,
    val question_count: Int,
    val bump: Int
)
```

Error:
`fetchQuestionCount Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Size must be known in advance when using READ_ALL`

Comment: The only thing I can see is that some of the examples also wrap the serializer in a `BorshAsBase64JsonArraySerializer`, so depending on how your API is configured, you might need to do that. https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/SolanaKT/blob/0f914ea2da9d30a2c5492793fde7413fd8a32105/README.md?plain=1#L205